# Firing an addEventListener "onclick" instead of "click"

Tags: jquery, html

I currently have a button like

`<span class="ripples">Click</span>`

where I am adding a ripple effect when someone clicks it. I am attaching the effect like this:

`document.addEventListener('click', addRippleEffect, false);`

and the effect is:

```
var addRippleEffect = function (e) {
    var target = e.target;
    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'span') return false;
    var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
    var ripple = target.querySelector('.ripple');
    if (!ripple) {
        ripple = document.createElement('span');
        ripple.className = 'ripple';
        ripple.style.height = ripple.style.width = Math.max(rect.width, rect.height) + 'px';
        target.appendChild(ripple);
    }
    ripple.classList.remove('show');
    var top = e.pageY - rect.top - ripple.offsetHeight / 2 - document.body.scrollTop;
    var left = e.pageX - rect.left - ripple.offsetWidth / 2 - document.body.scrollLeft;
    ripple.style.top = top + 'px';
    ripple.style.left = left + 'px';
    ripple.classList.add('show');
    return false;
}
```

That works perfectly.

Now, the problem is I want to fire an `onclick` if the button is clicked, like:

`<span class="ripples" onclick="open();">Click</span>`

This also works, however the ripple effect seems to disappear, probably because the `onclick` is firing before the `click` registers (I am just guessing here).

How do I fix this so that the effect also shows `onclick`?

Comment: Just add the call to `open` at the end of the `addRippleEffect` function

Comment: The code of your additional onclick handler is important.

Comment: @LucaKiebel I would, but it contains parameters that I need to pass.

Comment: @charlietfl It calls an ajax function and if successful redirects to another page.

Comment: The attribute onclick refers to the same event as the eventlistener "click". The only difference is that one is on the document and the other on the span. It therefore might be that your function open swallows the event before the document gets it.

Comment: Really need a *runnable* [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. Will help others help you without a lot of guessing

Comment: Move your JS code from the end of the document to its `HEAD` element and use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...)`.